# How to concatenate regular expressions in z3py?

Tags: z3, z3py

I want to construct a regular expression such as a* b* c*, There is a function re.++ in z3 that can concatenate 3 regular expressions together so I can construct a* b* c* as below

```
(assert (str.in.re "aabbc" (re.++ (re.* (str.to.re "a")) (re.* (str.to.re "b")) (re.* (str.to.re "c")))))
(check-sat)
```

However, I can't find such concatenation function in z3py API in the
website: https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/namespacez3py.html

So my question is how can I concatenate multiple regular expressions using z3py?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Concat`:

```py
>>> from z3 import *
>>> print(Concat(Star(Re("a")), Star(Re("b")), Star(Re("c"))))
re.++(Star(Re("a")), re.++(Star(Re("b")), Star(Re("c"))))
```